# How set Padding when an button is touched but the pointer is out of my button?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, touch

I use a XML file to display a button with 2 states (normal, pressed). How can I
find out when the button is touched but the cursor is out?

I want button effect like this

**button [not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yNmn.png) touched**

**button [touched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNzYw.png)**

**button touched but [finger hasn't been lifted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjSXB.png)**

Here is the XML file I use:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_press" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_nopress" />
</selector>
```

And here is my Java class:

```
button = findViewById(R.id.b1);
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    button.setPadding(0, 55, 0, 0);
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    button.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

And here is my button with my code:

**button touched but [finger hasn't been lifted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyjY1.png)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I can do it with this code:

```
private Rect rect;    // Variable rect to hold the bounds of the view
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        // Construct a rect of the view's bounds
        rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        if(!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())){
            // User moved outside bounds
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

the attribute state_pressed or the state_focused should do the job.
see the following [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button) for more guidance

Comment: It's not working. `android:state_focused="true"` only works when using the arrow keys on the keyboard. :(